# Can't log in with facebooks's php example?

Tags: php, facebook, oauth-2.0

I have been trying to get this to work for a few days on and off and seem to get no where with it. what ever I try I get

> You are not Connected. Public profile of Naitik

I am using a shared ssl does this have any to do with this?
I am guessing its an  OAuth 2.0 that is giving me problems?
if I go to `https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=IDNUMBER&redirect_uri=https://apps.facebook.com/...` I can see all my info
but if I just click the app from facebook's homepage it will say I am not logged in? 
any ideas?
Thank you!

```
<?php


require 'src/facebook.php';

// Create our Application instance (replace this with your appId and secret).
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => '...',
  'secret' => '...',
));

// Get User ID
$user = $facebook->getUser();


if ($user) {
  try {
    // Proceed knowing you have a logged in user who's authenticated.
    $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
  } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    error_log($e);
    $user = null;
  }
}

// Login or logout url will be needed depending on current user state.
if ($user) {
  $logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl();
} else {
  $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl();
}

// This call will always work since we are fetching public data.
$naitik = $facebook->api('/naitik');

?>
<!doctype html>
<html xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
  <head>
    <title>php-sdk</title>
    <style>
      body {
        font-family: 'Lucida Grande', Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
      }
      h1 a {
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #3b5998;
      }
      h1 a:hover {
        text-decoration: underline;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>php-sdk</h1>

    <?php if ($user): ?>
      <a href="<?php echo $logoutUrl; ?>">Logout</a>
    <?php else: ?>
      <div>
        Login using OAuth 2.0 handled by the PHP SDK:
        <a href="<?php echo $loginUrl; ?>">Login with Facebook</a>
      </div>
    <?php endif ?>

    <h3>PHP Session</h3>
    <pre><?php print_r($_SESSION); ?></pre>

    <?php if ($user): ?>
      <h3>You</h3>
      <img src="https://graph.facebook.com/<?php echo $user; ?>/picture">

      <h3>Your User Object (/me)</h3>
      <pre><?php print_r($user_profile); ?></pre>
    <?php else: ?>
      <strong><em>You are not Connected.</em></strong>
    <?php endif ?>

    <h3>Public profile of Naitik</h3>
    <img src="https://graph.facebook.com/naitik/picture">
    <?php echo $naitik['name']; ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you give some more details?  The script you pasted above is running on your server somewhere I assume, and you've made a facebook canvas app that loads it?  I'm confused about the initial part where you say you just keep getting that error message.  Any more info on what is on the page, where you see the error, etc?

Comment: Can you set a break point in your server code to step thru it?

Comment: yes this script is on my server and I also have a facebook canvas app that loads it. I dont get an error message but this script should display info about my self but instead it tells me I need to log in to facebook (and this is happening to me while I am on facebook and at the canvas app)

I don't know how to set a break point in php but I have tested some things out and it looks like where ever there is **if ($user)** it is false. If I try to display my id it is zero.

Comment: 0 means you have not authenticated the app.  Are you seeing this in IE only, or do other browsers also do the same thing?

Comment: I am having the same problem using facebook's example code on a shared (mediatemple)server.  Have you found a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a few more permissions like read_friendlist so that the API throws an exception on the statement `$fb->api('/me')` when the user is logged out as you want it to. For eg. set

```
$params = array('scope' => 'read_friendlists, friends_photos');
//$facebook->getLoginUrl($params);
//$facebook->getLogoutUrl($params);
// now use these login logout urls
```

You can also try adding `$params = array('next'=> 'your-landing-page')` to your facebook login request as `$fb->loginUrl($params)`.